# Fetch storage data and convert it to primitive types with subxt

Tags: rust, smart-contract, subxt, nft

I want to get the bool value from the flipper contract. I use Rust and subxt. But I cannot convert it to a primitive type.

```rust
    let value: bool = api
        .metadata()
        .pallet("test_contract")
        .map_err(|err| ErrorInternalServerError(err))?
        .storage("value")
        .map_err(|err| ErrorInternalServerError(err))?;
```

I have tried the `conv` and `into` methods. Also the `decode` but no luck.
The error I'm seeing is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `bool: std::convert::From<&frame_metadata::v14::StorageEntryMetadata<PortableForm>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/controllers/polkadot.rs:55:10
   |
55 |         .into();
   |          ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<&frame_metadata::v14::StorageEntryMetadata<PortableForm>>` is not implemented for `bool`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <bool as std::convert::From<core_foundation::boolean::CFBoolean>>
             <bool as std::convert::From<parity_wasm::elements::primitives::VarUint1>>
             <bool as std::convert::From<subtle::Choice>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<bool>` for `&frame_metadata::v14::StorageEntryMetadata<PortableForm>`
```

Also without into:

```
   = note: `?` operator cannot convert from `&frame_metadata::v14::StorageEntryMetadata<PortableForm>` to `bool`
   = note:   expected type `bool`
           found reference `&frame_metadata::v14::StorageEntryMetadata<PortableForm>`
```

Comment: What is the error you see?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi The error I'm seeing is now updated.

Comment: why are you calling `metadata()` if you are trying to access storage?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Because I need a StorageEntry for for the fetch function: https://docs.rs/subxt/latest/subxt/storage/struct.StorageClient.html#method.fetch

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi is right, what you are doing here is reading from the `metadata()` definition itself. See my answer for how to do what you want

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the bool value from the flipper contract

In order to read the return value of a contract message, you need to invoke it via RPC, a so called "dry-run", since calling it via a transaction will not return a value.

You would need to construct a request and then call the `"contracts_call"` rpc  method. At the current time there is no library available to do this, you would have to copy code from [`cargo-contract`](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/blob/cfd55bd66811f959e465bd7f1b6d5d60e2240fbc/src/cmd/extrinsics/call.rs#L90)

If on the other hand you did want to invoke a state changing contract transaction with `subxt` (e.g. `flip` in your case) you will need to invoke `call` on the contracts pallet e.g.:

```
api
        .tx()
        .contracts()
        .call(
            contract_address,
            value,
            gas_limit,
            storage_deposit_limit,
            data,
        )
        .sign_and_submit_then_watch_default(signer)
        .await?;
```

`data` will need to be populated with the `selector` of the contract message, together with the encoded args. The code above is copied from [`cargo-contract`](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/blob/cfd55bd66811f959e465bd7f1b6d5d60e2240fbc/src/cmd/extrinsics/call.rs#L163).

If you are just experimenting and don't want to integrate the above calls into your codebase, I recommend using [`cargo-contract`](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract) to interact with the contract during development.